# How do I collapse arrays in Mongo aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I can get this result of nested arrays from a Mongo aggregation:

```
"vals": [
[ [ { "reference_date": "2013-09-01", "price": 79 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-09-02", "price": 69 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-09-03", "price": 101 }, ] ],
[ [ { "reference_date": "2013-08-01", "price": 101 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-08-02", "price": 106 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-08-03", "price": 101 }, ] ],
[ [ { "reference_date": "2013-07-01", "price": 129 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-07-02", "price": 163 },
    { "reference_date": "2013-07-03", "price": 192 }, ] ],
```

]

I am using this query:

```
coll.aggregate([
{ $match:   { 'account_id': '123', }, },
{ $group: {
        _id: { 'account': '$account_id' },
        vals: { $push: '$data.prices' } }, },
]);
```

My base documents look like this:

```
{'account_id': '123',
  . . .  other stuff . . . 
  'data': [{
       'prices': [ 
          { "reference_date": "2013-08-01", "price": 101 },
          { "reference_date": "2013-08-02", "price": 106 },
          { "reference_date": "2013-08-03", "price": 101 }, 
        ],
        . . . other stuff under data key . . . 
   }]
```

**How can I modify the query so the nested arrays are combined into a single array**, holding nothing but the object items?

**UPDATED**:
To provide a more complete view of the base documents.  Sorry that wasn't there before.

**UPDATE 2**
Meh, I'm a lousy question asker, my << data >> subdoc fails b/c the value under data isn't an object, it is an array holding only one object.  I'm futzing about about trying to figure out the extraction of that object, at which the answer will work.

Comment: to clarify: do your base documents actually have doubly-nested arrays? That is, your examples are all arrays of arrays with one entry which is an array of documents: `[[obj1,obj2,obj3]],[[obj4,obj5,obj6]],...` are you arrays actually double-wrapped like this or was that a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** to reflect full doc details

You need to `$unwind` your `data` and `data.prices` arrays before your `$group`:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
  { $unwind: '$data' },
  { $unwind: '$data.prices' },
  { $match: { 'account_id': '123' } },
  { $group: {
    _id: { 'account': '$account_id' },
    vals: { $push: '$data.prices' } } }
]);
```

Comment: Thx for looking.  I've provided more of the document, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The only adjustment to the first update is to put '{ $unwind: '$data' },' before the data.prices unwind.  That compensates for the fact that the data key holds an array with one element, not an object -- I guess that first unwind lifts the object out of that array.  My apologies for the poor documentation of the base object, and thanks for all your help.

Comment: @chernevik Okay, I updated the answer for that.  Glad it worked in the end!